# Should I factor in Thanksgiving rush at Atlanta airport?

Tags: air-travel, airports, public-holidays, atl

I have an evening flight on Thanksgiving (27th Nov) which departs at around 9 PM. I am usually in the (any) airport an hour before any (domestic/international) flight. However, I have never flown around holidays. Should I be factoring in Thanksgiving rush and arrive earlier? Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Domestic or international? And though it matters less at ATL than at some other airports, which airline?

Comment: @choster International. Delta

Answer (score 5):

In large Airports (and ATL is a Large airport), I usually am there much more than an hour in advance. There are too many things that could go wrong, including, but not limited to:

- Increased number of Travelers on and around Holiday Dates
- Winter weather (ATL isn't too bad with this, in my experiences.)
- Longer lines in Security
- Longer lines everywhere.

I have flown through both ATL and LAX on and around Thanksgiving and Christmas Before, (Last year, in fact,) and I am glad that I arrived early. Because I fly for business, but still ride coach, I usually like to show up 2 hours in advance. That is both my opinion, and my company policy, and it has never failed me. For me, it's not just about being able to run and catch my gate, its about being there a little early so I dont have to sit on the floor or stand while I wait at my gate. Just personal preference!

Good luck with your flight, and enjoy your Thanksgiving!

Comment: You say ATL isn't too bad with that... But 2 years ago when flying into ATL, about half of our company was delayed by up to 24 hours for weather related reasons... so it does happen :)

Comment: Could you include any specifics ? This is the same advise which the airlines give. Do you have any experience flying through ATL around thanksgiving ?